# Solver.solve() returns seeming random solution and score, not best

Tags: optaplanner

**What I Have**

Using OptaPlanner 7.45.0.Final on Java 8.

I am working on a proof-of-concept for scheduling of shifts, where I have created `CrewAssignment` object as a `@PlanningEntity`.

I have created my own `EasyScoreCalculator` implementation (from the new non-deprecated `EasyScoreCalculator`).

The score function returns a `HardMediumSoftScore`, with Hard representing physical possibility (can't be in 2 places at once, can't take on an activity that starts in a different place than the previous activity ended), Medium representing legal issues (maximum work day, etc.), and Soft roughly representing financial concerns.

**The behavior I am getting**

The schedule seemed to work well for small datasets where there are many good possible `Solution`s.  However, when I moved to larger datasets, it had a harder time returning good final schedules.  There would be scores like -60hard/-390060medium/-1280457soft, which seems really bad.  Moreover, if I increased the time available, the score would sometimes get worse!

**Things I have tried**

I put a print in my score function for the score being calculated.  It would often give scores such as 0hard/0medium/-2250411soft, which in comparison to the final scores is great!  However, the final result would still be a bad score.

I added a `SolverEventListener` to the `Solver`, and it is only called once at the very end of the solving.

I thought maybe there was a problem with cloning of the `Solution`, so I created my own `SolutionCloner`.  It is called once at the beginning, and twice at the end.  Since it is called so infrequently, I suspect the solver uses the first `Solution` clone as the best score, tries to copy the values from the current `Solution` iteration to the best `Solution`, but given that the `SolverEventListener` is only called once, that may indicate that it is not recognizing the best solution.

I tried simplifying to a `HardSoftScore` by combining Hard and Medium values, but the behavior is the same.

I tried calling `solverConfig.setEnvironmentMode(EnvironmentMode.NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT);` (yes, I'm programatically creating the `SolverConfig`, but the behavior does not change.

**Relevant Code Snippets**

Subset of the `CrewAssignment` `@PlanningEntity`:

```
@PlanningEntity
public final class CrewAssignment
{
    private Long crewMemberId;
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"crewMemberId"})
    public Long getCrewMemberId() { return crewMemberId; }
    public void setCrewMemberId(Long value) { crewMemberId = value; }

    @Override
    protected CrewAssignment clone()
    {
        CrewAssignment newAssignment = new CrewAssignment(getActivities());
        newAssignment.setCrewMemberId(crewMemberId);

        return newAssignment;
    }
}
```

Subset of the `Solution`:

```
@PlanningSolution(solutionCloner = CrewSchedSolutionCloner.class)
public final class CrewSchedSolution
{
    private final List<Long> crewMemberIds;
    @ValueRangeProvider(id="crewMemberId")
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    public List<Long> getCrewMemberIds() { return crewMemberIds; }

    // assignments
    private List<CrewAssignment> crewAssignments = new ArrayList<>();
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    public List<CrewAssignment> getCrewAssignments() { return crewAssignments; }

    HardSoftScore score;
    @PlanningScore
    public HardSoftScore getScore() { return score; }
    public void setScore(HardSoftScore value) { score = value; }

    public CrewSchedSolution cloneSolution()
    {
        List<CrewAssignment> newCrewAssignments = new ArrayList<>(crewAssignments);
        for (int i = 0; i < newCrewAssignments.size(); i++)
        {
            CrewAssignment existingAssignment = newCrewAssignments.get(i);
            CrewAssignment newAssignment = existingAssignment.clone();
            newCrewAssignments.set(i, newAssignment);
        }
        return new CrewSchedSolution(/* Various additional data */,
            crewMemberIds,
            newCrewAssignments, score);
    }
}
```

The `SolutionCloner`:

```
public final class CrewSchedSolutionCloner
    implements SolutionCloner<CrewSchedSolution>
{
    @Override
    public CrewSchedSolution cloneSolution(CrewSchedSolution originalSolution)
    {
        return originalSolution.cloneSolution();
    }
}
```

**Summary**

I have run out of obvious (to me) ways to debug this further.  It kind of feels like the good values are getting written over, but I can't prove that yet.  I might be able to come up with a way of saving the values set in the `CrewAssignment` `@PlanningEntity` just to get it to work, but it seems like that is something OptaPlanner was designed to be able to handle.

The problem is too large to post a SSCCE.  I have posted what I think might be relevant.  Let me know if there is any other part of the code you would need to see.  Thanks in advance!

P.S. I realize this may be a duplicate of [OptaPlanner return the best score but not its associated solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60886263/optaplanner-return-the-best-score-but-not-its-associated-solution), but the original poster never followed up with the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OptaPlanner was (of course) working correctly.  I had a conceptual misunderstanding.

I was focusing on the `Score`s I was calculating, and not focusing on the scores that OptaPlanner was actually using.  OptaPlanner can augment the `Score`s that are returned from the scoring function by adding an "init" value representing the number of uninitialized `@PlanningVariable`s.  Scores that had 0 Hard and Medium scores may have looked reasonable, but may still be uninitialized, which takes precedence over Hard/Medium/Soft values.

Once the duration of the simulation was set sufficiently high, all `@PlanningVariable`s were being set.  No scores with init of 0 were created after that, and completed optimized solutions (whether infeasible or feasible) were computed.

See the steps Geoffrey outlined for debugging.  If you are using JDK logging, you may have to add slf4j-api and slf4j-jdk14 jars to your path.

See the documentation, section 2.3.6 "Gather the domain objects in a planning solution", where it describes the difference between an "uninitialized", "infeasible", and "feasible" solution.

Note: It appears that the solver does not notify `SolverEventListener`s when the best solution so far is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

*if I increased the time available, the score would sometimes get worse!* That is impossible (if it gets more steps in the second run, which it should, and it is a reproducible run, which it is).

Does the `DEBUG` log show it's running more "LS step" lines? If it does, you might have score corruption, but NON_INTRUSIVE_FULL_ASSERT or FULL_ASSERT would detect that if they run long enough (much longer than without because they are slower).

Normally, optaplanner runs are 100% reproducible, given the same amount of steps (~ same amount of time give or take a few steps). Check your `DEBUG` log if that's the case. Simulated Annealing isn't reproducible, but that's off by default.

**OptaPlanner Benchmark is your best friend.** Especially the BEST_SCORE graph and the score calculation speed number. Run it 4 times longer, so you can see how the BEST_SCORE graph behaves if given more time. Also, `subSingleCount` might be an interesting thing to turn on here, to see how sensitive the optimization is to a good random seed (it shouldn't be).

Comment: I turned on debugging (had to manually add slf4j-api and slf4j-jdk14 jars to my pre-Maven project), and realized the score I am returning gets modified with an "init" value (of higher priority than hard/medium/soft) when there are null `@PlanningVariable`s, and that modified score determines fitness.  This was my reason for thinking the score was getting worse when it wasn't.  Lengthening the duration of the solver resulted in init values of 0, with my score being used as returned.  This ended up being a dumb user problem; thanks for giving me the information to find the problem!

Comment: Side note: Your answer gave me steps to help find the problem. As far as StackOverflow norms, I am not sure whether now I am supposed to accept this answer, or create a new answer with the actual solution and accept that.

Comment: Create a new answer with the actual, accepted solution is clearer for other OptaPlanner users viewing this question later by finding it through google - I don't mind the lack of karma gain :)

Answer (score 0):

Ow, wait. You wrote your own solution cloner? That's probably it, because solution cloners are extremely difficult to write correctly. Disable that and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  However, the problem pre-existed the `SolutionCloner` that I created, and the behavior was the same when I removed it again.  I am looking into your other answer.